# WARNING:root:Variable [...] is not available in checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train a model to detect trunks.
I've already prepared my inputs.
So, I'm executing the training script in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit script on error.
set -e
# Echo each command, easier for debugging.
set -x

export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:`pwd`/slim:$PYTHONPATH

num_training_steps=500
num_eval_steps=100

MODEL_DIR="/home/andre-criis/Source/coral/detect/models/research/models/mobilenet_v2"
TRAIN_DIR=train_dir
mkdir "${TRAIN_DIR}"

python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=${MODEL_DIR}/pipeline.config \
  --model_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --num_train_steps="${num_training_steps}" \
  --num_eval_steps="${num_eval_steps}" \
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
  --alsologtostderr
```

However, I'm stuck in this error:

```
WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases] is not available in checkpoint
...
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv/project/BatchNorm/gamma] is not available in checkpoint
...
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/BatchNorm/gamma] is not available in checkpoint
```

It's weird because I'm creating an empty directory for the train (as can be seen above) and the parameter `from_detection_checkpoint` is set to `true` in my `pipeline.config`.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.